# If I add a UISwitch control to each of my table view cells, how can I tell which cell it belongs to?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uiswitch

I have a `UITableView` with cells that contain a `UISwitch` control.  It's similar to the table view in the iPhone's Clock app shown below...

[image]
<sub>(source: [epicself.com](http://epicself.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/1-1.jpg))</sub>

In my app's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I create and attach the `UISwitch` control like so...

```
 CGRect frameSwitch = CGRectMake(215.0, 10.0, 94.0, 27.0);
 UISwitch *switchEnabled = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frameSwitch];
 [switchEnabled addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 cell.accessoryView = switchEnabled;
```

My question is, when the switch is toggled by the user and the `switchToggled` method is called, how can I tell which table cell it belongs to?  I can't really do much with it without knowing it's context.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your action method, you can cast the `superview` of the passed-in `UISwitch` (which is the `UITableViewCell` itself), then pass that to the `tableView`'s `indexPathForCell` method.

`indexPathForCell` will return a `NSIndexPath` object, which you can then use to index to your datamodel to modify. Then all you gotta do is call `reloadData` on your `tableView`.

Also, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should set the `UISwitch`'s state based on your model.

Comment: this is actually a much better approach because it doesn't use up the tag attribute, which is usually a good thing to have available, thanks!

Comment: Just for those who still found a problem with the superview, sometimes  you need to point to the superview of the superview of the control since the control might be in the UITableViewCellContentView. The superview to the UITableViewCellContentView will be the required UITableViewCell

Answer (score 9):

First of all, fix the memory leak:

```
UISwitch *switchEnabled = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frameSwitch] autorelease];
```

Then pick one of these options:

```
switchEnabled.tag = someInt; // before adding it to the cell

NSLog(@"switched %d",switch.tag); // to see which switch was toggled
```

or

```
UITableViewCell *parentCell = switchEnabled.superview;
// + some magic to see which cell this actually is
```

Comment: +1 for `.tag`. That's the simplest way. Load that up with the index into the array of data you're populating the table from.

Comment: thanks, mvds!  the tag property will do nicely!  there was no leak, i just forgot to include my release call in the question.